# Using jQuery how would you create the following output from this input?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Given this input:

```
const input = ['and','AND_DEFINITION']
```

Create an Object which look like this:

```
{
    letter: 'a'
    definition: null,
    children: [{
        letter: 'n',
        definition: null,
        children: [{
            letter: d,
            definition: 'AND_DEFINITION'
        }]
    }]
}
```

I believe the first thing to do is to run a for loop and then split the first item of the array

```
const input = ['and','AND_DEFINITION']

for for (i= 0; i<input.length; i++) {

}
```

But I don't know where to go from here

Comment: You *don't* want to loop `i<input.length` because you only have one value - the letter, it's two children and the definition.  So you would not start with a loop (of `input.length`)

Answer (score 0):

USE `Object.assign([], string)`

This function will convert string to array of characters.

You can access your required character as per your need.

[Read More about Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const input = ['and','AND_DEFINITION'];

var text_1 = input[0];
var text_arr = Object.assign([], text_1);

alert(text_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is this different from a simple `input[0].split('')` ?